# Plugin not displayed on Outlook 2007

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I have created an Outlook Plugin that works perfectly in Office 2010/2013. It is shown on the main screen of Outlook(where we see all the emails). Somehow it doesn't show up in Outlook 2007.

I have implemented a class using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.OfficeRibbon
In the ribbon type, I am providing Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer

Is it possible that Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer is not supported in Outlook 2007? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook 2007 uses ribbons only on inspectors. Explorers still used the old Explorer.CommandBars interface. Explorers switched to using ribbons in Outlook 2010.